# ASP.Net Core Web App Navigation Issue - It seems it is not executing the Action Method

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I published my webApp on [www.eWisdom.lk](http://www.ewisdom.lk). When I try to login by using a correct password and username it forwad it to the correct action method but it seems it is not executing. It shows a blank page. If you can please visit my URL with these credentials (User Name - "Grade6" Password - "12012") and give me some advice to correct my fault.

I would like to mention here, it works well when I run it locally. When it works as I wish it displays following screen.
[Image of the screen](http://prntscr.com/wggyp3)

Codes for your references.

1. .cshtml

```
               {
                   
                   <input required type="text" id="login" asp-for="UserName" class="fadeIn second" placeholder="User Name"> <br />
                   <input required type="password" asp-for="Password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" placeholder="Password">                 
                   <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
               }
```

2. Controller

- Account.cs

```
public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

```
       [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult LoginPost(LoginViewModel obj)
        {            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = loginManager.PasswordSignInAsync(obj.UserName, obj.Password,false, false).Result;               
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("UserLogin_Suc", "Login");                  
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["msgErr"] = "Invalid Login data";
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect User Name or Password!");
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
                }
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login Data!");
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
```

3. Controller
   Login.cs

```
public ActionResult UserLogin_Suc(){
     MyIdentityUser user = userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User).Result;
     string Id = user.WisdomUserId;
     string Type = user.UserType;
     if (Type == "Student"){
     var status2 = _context.Students.Where(o => o.StudentId == Id && o.Status == "NY"); 
if (status2.Count() > 0){ 
return RedirectToAction("ResetNewYear", "Students"); 
}
}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind the above is a permission issue of Database files. I resolved it by setting correct permissions and ownerships of .mdf and .ldf files.

Thank you.